# How to debug a NullPointerException in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

I have a very simple app which isn't starting correctly.  The app should load a splashscreen, and then the main app.  For some reason it's now not working -

Logcat:

```
    02-08 13:30:41.846: E/AndroidRuntime(275): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.KES.GApps/com.KES.GApps.Splashscreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1860)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1756)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1736)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:217)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1633)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.KES.GApps.Splashscreen.onCreate(Splashscreen.java:13)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
02-08 13:30:41.865: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  ... 11 more
02-08 13:30:41.884: I/dalvikvm(275): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-08 13:30:41.884: E/dalvikvm(275): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

xml for the splashscreen (welcome.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/img1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/crestinfo"
        android:src="@drawable/logov2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomescreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/welcomescreen"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:padding="5dp" android:textSize="15pt" />

</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
package com.KES.GApps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Splashscreen extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
        Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               try {
                  int waited = 0;
                  while (waited < 2000) {
                     sleep(100);
                     waited += 100;
                  }
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  // do nothing
               } finally {
                  finish();
                  Intent i = new Intent();
                  i.setClassName("com.KES.GApps",
                                 "com.KES.GApps.KingEdwardVIISchoolActivity");
                  startActivity(i);
               }
            }
         };
         splashThread.start();
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.KES.GApps"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.5" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="KingEdwardVIISchool"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="standard" >
        <activity
            android:name="KingEdwardVIISchoolActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Splashscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you have a welcome.xml file in your res/layout directory? Has the R.java autogeneration succeed?

Comment: If welcome.xml was missing it wouldn't compile. My guess is that it has something to do with `startActivity(i);`

Comment: The first thing I suggest is cleaning the project.  According to the error, it's crashing at `setContentView` which suggests to me that it can't find the layout.  In Eclipse, select Project->Clean then rebuild it if you don't have it set to rebuild automatically.

Comment: Could you show the `welcome.xml` layout, please?

Comment: Yes we need to see welcome.xml

Comment: Sorry the xml section was the welcome.xml, I've renamed the section so its clear.

Answer (score 0):

According to the LogCat output the problem is in your `welcome.xml` layout file. It is inflated incorrectly for some reason.

Try removing `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"` attribute and **ENSURE** that you have run `Clean..` command on your project before the launch.

Also **ENSURE** that all the references in the xml-file are valid (i.e. `logov2`, `img1`). I would temporarily remove all references from your xml-file and check if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions.  I have cleaned and check that its building automatically, which it is.  The xml section above is the welcome.xml, sorry if that wasn't clear. I've also tried removing the android:textAppearance bit too.

Comment: Try removing all references from `welcome.xml` and leave there just one `TextView` with hardcoded text (no backgrounds, no `ImageView`, no `android:textAppearance` and so on) and see if it works.

Comment: Again thats for your help, I've tried deleting the welcome.xml and recreating a very simple page with just text, but thats not work either, I wonder if the java is messed up.

Comment: Make sure, that you get exactly the same exceptions after your manipulations. I mean, you see these stack trace:
`... 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1860)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1756) 
...`

Answer (score 0):

Copy the welcome.xml file and save it anywhere for temporary time then delete this file from the eclipse after delete the file again paste that welcome.xml file which you copied.Then run again.It will sure run your app.

Comment: The xml section above is the welcome.xml. Sorry it that wasn't clear.

Comment: have you did as i suggest you???PhoneWindow Message as in your logcat is due to this problem.i faced same as you and get the same Phonewindow error and then i did as i suggest you.SO Please try this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but thats not worked. Its a very strange one!

Answer (score 0):

I was also suffering from this problem once. Then what i did was i just copied the `id` of the layout from my `R.java` and pasted it directly to `setContentView()`. ie, Here in your case the `id` of welcome in `R.java`->`layout`. then my app ran successfully without any exception. Thus i realized that its just a temporary problem. After restarting my eclipse (sometimes you have to restart your system fully) I replaced the id again by `R.layout.welcome` and it worked fine.
Hope this helps...

Answer (score -3):

Have you added the activity in to the manifest and also added the permission?

Please add the manifest so that I can refer you something more?

You have crash may be due to this Permission denied.
Check your permission in the manifest.xml.

Comment: This would give different output

Comment: This would give following output: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {your_class_here}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: have you check the permission denied problem in the log cat.i know this error come but i give suggestion on permission denied base.Everyone know about this error when this come which you refer me.ok