# Sending information to the internet and receiving something back

Tags: android, url, qr-code

My goal for an app is to be able to write some information in an edit text box and click a button, when I click that button I want a QR Code to be made with all the information I have writen out. How I have this envisioned in my head right now is using zxing. However I dont know how to do apart of it. I need to know how to send some information to the internet then return what was printed. So with the zxing I know that I am able to write out a QR Code very easily by editing a url. (http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chld=L&choe=UTF-8&chl=Hello+My+Name+Is+Michael) and I can do that all fine but once I have the url that is needed how can I make my app send that url to the internet copy the QR Code and send me back the image? Is this even possible? I would like to hear your feed back on this, thanks.

Comment: You just download the image at the URL. (This is not zxing -- it is the precursor to the encoder in the project though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the url, you should create a Bitmap and do the request to Google. You can do it in this way:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
    bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
    Bitmap bm = LoadImage(image_URL, bmOptions);

.....

private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options)
{       
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;       
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
        in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        /*ERROR DO SOMETHING ERROR*/
        }
    return bitmap;               
}
```

I hope it's usuful for you.

Comment: seam good, however when I put that code in I get an error on "OpenHttpConnection" saying that it is not defined in my activity, do I need to make a method for this or do I need an import?

Answer (score 1):

You are right! Sorry I missed a piece of code:

```
InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException{
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
               inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
        /* ERROR  DO SOMETHING */
        }
        return inputStream;
    }
```

Comment: When I run my app using this stuff I get a NullPointerException, I am assuming that this is because the bitmap is being pasted through as null and when I try to set my image view to this it chrashes. What have I done wronge though? I put the section of code above the "...." in your last answer in onClickListener and then I put the oher two methods as a method below the main code so it gets used as it gets called then I say `QRCode.setImageBitmap(bm);` also in onClickListener but after the other lines of code.

Comment: You shuold find the point of NullPointerException. You copy here the stack of your error.

Comment: sorry what do you want me to copy? What is a stack of your error?

Comment: stack trace contains informations about you error, here you can see an example:[example stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194945/beginer-at-android-apps-please-help-nullpointerexception) . You can find it in [Logcat](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)

Comment: So it turns out I made a mistake, it isnt your code that is messed up it is mine, I cant out spaces in my qr code without it crashing. but if I run a one word qr code it works so Thank you! now I just have to debug my end